# Dynamically generating ember-data models in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli app where I need to dynamically generate some ember data models based on configuration data that resides in a remote location. I have an initializer which defers application readiness, and fetches the config data via ajax.

Now in an old-school ember app, from that point I would simply generate my `DS.Model` objects and assign them to the global `App` ember application instance. However, in an ember-cli I am not sure how to define the models so that they can be found by the rest of the application, since by default ember-cli's resolver generates models and their name based on filename/directory structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was a bit simpler than I thought. Basically just needed to use `Ember.Application.register` in my initializer for each model that I dynamically generated, like so:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import request from "ic-ajax";
import DS from "ember-data";

export default {
    name: 'model-config',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        application.deferReadiness();

        request('/path/to/model/config/data').then(function(response) {
            Ember.$.each(response.tables, function(modelName, modelCfg) {
                var cfg = {};

                Ember.$.each(modelCfg, function(fieldName, fieldCfg) {
                    if(typeof fieldCfg === 'string') {
                        cfg[fieldName] = DS.attr(fieldCfg);
                    } else {
                        cfg[fieldName] = DS[fieldCfg.type](fieldCfg.model);
                    }
                });

                application.register('model:' + modelName, DS.Model.extend(cfg));
            });

            application.advanceReadiness();
        });
    }
};
```